# On Error Goto not being called on Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am reading a cell from a spreadsheet that should be a number but may or may not be `#N/A`.  In the past, if the cell value was `#N/A` I believe the On Error Goto routine would be invoked.

Setting the cell value to zero will not work in this application.  If the cell formula returns `#N/A`, I need it to remain `#N/A` instead of making it zero.

```
Option Explicit
    Dim Piecerate_Labor as Single
    Dim ErrorList() as Variant
    Dim UniqueID as String
    Dim CurrentStyleError as Boolean
    'Other code removed

Sub GetCostInfo()
        On Error GoTo Errorhandler
        'Other code removed
        With Workbooks("Cost_Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Cost")
            Piecerate_Labor = .Range("Piecerate_Labor_Cost").Value
            'Other code removed
        End With
    Exit Sub

    Errorhandler:
        ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        ErrorList(ErrorCount, 1) = UniqueID
        'Other Coe Removed     Workbooks("Cost_Master.xlsm").Worksheets("Cost").Range("P565").Value 'trap labor issue
        CurrentStyleError = True

End Sub
```

Code breaks on line `Piecerate_Labor =.Range("Piecerate_Labor_Cost").Value` with Run Time Error "13": Type Mismatch Error because `Piecerate_Labor is Single` and the value of `.Range("Piecerate_Labor_Cost")` is `#N/A`.  Before I believe it would invoke the On Error Goto Errorhandler.  Why will the type mismatch error not invoke the On Error Goto Errorhandler line?  It seems I am missing something pretty basic.

Comment: why not check the value of the cell for #N/A first?  excel.worksheetfunction.isna    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.isna

Comment: It is highly recommended to **not** use `On Error GoTo`. Instead, code for the possibility of `#N/A` rather try to ignore it. In pseudo code, `IF NOT ISNA THEN....`

Comment: I guess I had complete brain lock. I will check for N/A as suggested.  It was difficult to understand why it worked before.  thanks.

Comment: Do you have "Break on all errors" set (*Tools* > *Options* > *General*)? Thata would explain the current scenario.

Comment: If your error is not triggering your error handler, it's possible you have set "Break on all errors" in your VBA options. *Tools >> Options >> general*